# How do i fix this invalid character error in php?

Tags: php, xml, csv, xslt

I'm having to write a program for university that takes a CSV, parses and then creates a xml table from it. For that purpose I have written the following code:

```
<?php
    class WorldDataParser{
       function parseCSV(string $path) {
        //open the CSV document at the beginning, read only to read the data it contains
        $csv = fopen($path, "r");
        $rows = 0;
        $header = 0;
        //Loop through rows
        while (($container = fgetcsv($csv,2000,",")) !== FALSE) {
            $columnsInCSV = count($container); //amount of columns in CSV
            //iterating over the columns in CSV
            for ($currentColumn = 0; $currentColumn < $columnsInCSV; $currentColumn++) {
                if($rows !== 0){
                    $parsedData[$rows -1][$header[$currentColumn]] = $container[$currentColumn]; //filling in columns of respective headers
                } else { //when in first row of CSV
                    $header = $currentColumn; //get headers and put them into head 
                }
            }
            $rows++; //next row
        }
        //closing the CSV we opened at the begining
        fclose($csv);
        //parsed data is returned
        return $parsedData;
       }


       
   
       function saveXML(array $input) {
            //checking wether input 0
            if(count($input) == 0) {
                //if not stop function, return false
                return false;
            }
            //input that is not 0 is processed
            $xmlContainer = new DomDocument(); //empty Container Document, to be filled and saved
            $xml = $xmlContainer->appendChild($xmlContainer->createElement("Countries")); //create root-element
            
            for($x = 0; $x < count($input); $x++) {
                $countryContainer = $xmlContainer->createElement("Country"); //creating country element for each new country
                $xml->appendChild($countryContainer); //appending it to the xml
                $arrayContainer = $input[$x]; //creating container array for further use in while loop
                
                while($currentValue = current($arrayContainer)) { //loop for extracting the keys and values out of input
                    $key = key($arrayContainer); //key variable
                    $key = trim($key); //stripping whitespaces of key
                    $key = str_replace(" ", "_", $key); //to prevent Invalid Character Error
                    $currentValue = trim($currentValue); //stripping whitespaces of value
                    $element = $xmlContainer->createElement($key); //creating key element
                    $element->appendChild($xmlContainer->createTextNode($currentValue)); //appending value to element
                    $countryContainer->appendChild($element); //appending element to Country
                    next($arrayContainer);  //next key and value
                }
            }
            //making sure output is clean
            $xmlContainer->formatOutput = true;
            //saving the XML to style directory 
            $xmlContainer->save("world_data.xml");
            return true;
        }
        
        function printXML(string $pathOfXML, string $pathOfXSLT) {
            //loading XML file
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($pathOfXML);
            //loading XSLT file into container Document
            $xslt = new DOMDocument();
            $xslt->load($pathOfXSLT);

            //Using XSLTProcessor() to process XSLT
            $processor = new XSLTProcessor();
            $processor->importStylesheet($xslt);

            //creating output Variable to put transformed XML into
            $output = $processor->transformToXML($xml);
            //returning formated XML
            return $output;
        }
    }
?>
```

i get the following two error messages:

Invalid Character Error - #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/style/world_data_parser.php(51): DOMDocument->createElement('')

and

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /opt/lampp/htdocs/style/world_data_parser.php on line 14 , with the CSV given to us by the uni looking like this:

```
id ,name                ,birth rate per 1000,cell phones per 100,children per woman,electricity consumption per capita,gdp_per_capita,gdp_per_capita_growth,inflation annual,internet user per 100,life expectancy,military expenditure percent of gdp,gps_lat      ,gps_long
001,Brazil              ,16.405             ,90.01936334        ,1.862             ,2201.808724                       ,4424.758692   ,-1.520402823         ,8.228535058     ,39.22                ,74             ,1.615173655                        ,-14.235004000,-51.925280000
002,Canada              ,10.625             ,70.70997244        ,1.668             ,15119.76414                       ,25069.86915   ,-3.953353186         ,2.944408564     ,80.17086651          ,80.9           ,1.415710422                        ,56.130366000 ,-106.346771000
003,Chile               ,15.04              ,97.01862561        ,1.873             ,3276.06449                        ,6451.631126   ,-2.610485847         ,7.47050527      ,38.8                 ,78.8           ,3.064076139                        ,-35.675147000,71.542969000
004,China               ,13.536             ,55.97490921        ,1.642             ,2632.724637                       ,2208.403948   ,8.648414427          ,6.684109668     ,28.97659939          ,75.6           ,2.24110794                         ,35.86166000  ,104.19539700
005,Colombia            ,20.605             ,92.34584564        ,2.405             ,1041.994137                       ,3137.695335   ,0.2081538559         ,3.666941163     ,30                   ,75.3           ,3.833780372                        ,4.570868000  ,-74.297333000
006,Ecuador             ,20.989             ,92.84925653        ,2.69              ,1078.038961                       ,1692.067197   ,-1.079538461         ,7.595866872     ,24.6                 ,74.1           ,3.746501879                        ,-1.831239000 ,-78.183406000
007,Egypt               ,24.83              ,69.43661504        ,2.919             ,1607.918763                       ,1911.964501   ,2.856917581          ,10.10750976     ,24.28                ,70.2           ,2.137305699                        ,26.820553000 ,30.802498000
008,Finland             ,11.127             ,144.1530224        ,1.86              ,15241.61194                       ,26205.68832   ,-8.791558776         ,0.4277308694    ,82.53133098          ,79.7           ,1.501872268                        ,61.924110000 ,25.748151000
009,France              ,12.21              ,95.44434226        ,1.978             ,7339.946832                       ,22508.76261   ,-3.264056248         ,1.050366124     ,69.0633593           ,81             ,2.55313249                         ,46.22763800  ,2.21374900
010,Germany             ,8.136              ,127.4188883        ,1.376             ,6753.05764                        ,24368.19561   ,-4.886323581         ,0.5959234322    ,79.48523153          ,80             ,1.438871341                        ,51.165691000 ,10.451526000
011,Iceland             ,14.738             ,107.6604456        ,2.123             ,51259.18763                       ,35310.97441   ,-6.990418561         ,6.900703626     ,92.13686385          ,82.2           ,0.0820538039                       ,64.9630510000,-19.0208350000
012,Iraq                ,31.585             ,65.47478839        ,4.276             ,1086.323768                       ,752.1833548   ,1.141874289          ,25.22442136     ,1.047516616          ,68.1           ,4.621383386                        ,33.223191000 ,43.679291000
013,Japan               ,8.201              ,91.8955442         ,1.359             ,7838.005685                       ,38242.02429   ,-6.180260885         ,-2.08543109     ,77.38468963          ,82.8           ,1.019445017                        ,36.204824000 ,138.252924000
014,Kazakhstan          ,19.775             ,107.7147692        ,2.537             ,4447.142293                       ,2345.86415    ,-1.437812068         ,19.5422854      ,17.91457965          ,66.6           ,1.105385125                        ,48.019573000 ,66.923684000
015,Mexico              ,19.091             ,74.25785259        ,2.313             ,1869.82352                        ,5875.619997   ,-7.417438847         ,4.033645258     ,26.34                ,75.5           ,0.5396656609                       ,23.6345010000,-102.5527840000
016,New Zealand         ,13.831             ,108.7301521        ,2.125             ,9375.550304                       ,14778.16393   ,-1.552308788         ,3.486782259     ,79.82609287          ,80.3           ,1.140562366                        ,-40.900557000,174.885971000
017,Nigeria             ,40.134             ,48.23561006        ,6.021             ,119.8151486                       ,513.5003377   ,4.3526073            ,9.313146383     ,20                   ,58.5           ,0.8924302789                       ,9.0819990000 ,8.6752770000
018,Peru                ,21.342             ,85.86901405        ,2.545             ,1043.052601                       ,2955.186222   ,-0.2228977721        ,4.49134447      ,31.4                 ,76.7           ,1.348875763                        ,-9.189967000 ,-75.015152000
019,Russia              ,10.828             ,161.1162887        ,1.537             ,6132.978648                       ,2806.41483    ,-7.749103694         ,11.60398093     ,29.23584146          ,68.3           ,4.36259042                         ,61.52401000  ,105.31875600
020,Saudi Arabia        ,23.569             ,167.3474553        ,2.898             ,7430.743897                       ,9294.355996   ,-2.242127204         ,14.36222827     ,38                   ,77.6           ,10.95653405                        ,23.88594200  ,45.07916200
021,South Africa        ,22.113             ,93.33587369        ,2.5               ,4532.021902                       ,3697.67368    ,-2.732989408         ,7.861608575     ,10.08745979          ,55.8           ,1.394530379                        ,-30.559482000,22.937506000
022,Sweden              ,11.72              ,112.1241184        ,1.937             ,14143.01101                       ,30885.45914   ,-5.976535294         ,1.022227082     ,91.12326108          ,81.2           ,1.247701873                        ,60.128161000 ,18.643501000
023,United Arab Emirates,14.027             ,153.7997194        ,1.903             ,9998.291079                       ,22507.00157   ,-11.99171952         ,8.549032358     ,64                   ,76.1           ,5.834881976                        ,23.424076000 ,53.847818000
024,United Kingdom      ,12.195             ,130.1742603        ,1.89              ,5685.635995                       ,27933.77767   ,-5.019251823         ,2.861406642     ,77.79971962          ,79.7           ,2.667209048                        ,52.355517700 ,-1.174319700
025,United States       ,14.191             ,89.14911634        ,2.002             ,12913.71143                       ,36539.22823   ,-4.342271218         ,1.152326348     ,71.21181627          ,78.3           ,4.822730027                        ,37.090240000 ,-95.712891000
```

(i didn't edit it cause it might be causing the problem, with all the spaces in it)
I am very inexperienced in working with php, and im struggling to properly debug my code.

Comment: Please provide CSV data not just code for [mcve]. Issue appears to be how you create the raw XML particularly with `createElement`. We need to see values. No spaces, special characters except period/hyphen/underscore, leading digits are allowed in XML names.

Comment: @Parfait i added the CSV data to the question, i have already considered this causing problems, hence i wrote the $key = str_replace(" ", "_", $key); line to strip it of all the spaces that might be causing problems.

Comment: It seems you are trying to create an empty named element. Review `var_dump` of csv data array for empty elements (possibly from unused column in original csv data). Also, echo `$key` just before `$element = $xmlContainer->createElement($key);`. Then when code errs out check console of last `$key` print out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider simplfying your CSV parse and XML output:

```php
// CSV TO ARRAY (COLUMN HEADERS AS KEYS)
$raw = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
foreach($raw as $key => $data ) { $raw[$key] = array_combine($raw[0], $raw[$key]); }
$data = array_values(array_slice($raw, 1));

// INITIALIZE XML
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$root = $dom->createElement("Countries");
$root = $dom->appendChild($root);

// BUILD XML NODES
foreach($data as $d) {
   $cntyNode = $dom->createElement('Country');    

   foreach($d as $k=>$v) {
      $key = str_replace(" ", "_", trim($k));  // ECHO OUT FOR DEBUGGING
      $childNode = $dom->createElement($key, htmlspecialchars(trim($v)));
      $cntyNode->appendChild($childNode);
   }
   $root->appendChild($cntyNode);
}

// SAVE XML
file_put_contents("world_data.xml", $dom->saveXML());
```